# Finite state machine constructor - Racket Language

Tags: racket, fsm, dfa, state-machine, nfa

I need to build a finite machine constructor that accepts all of the prefixes of a given machine's language. Let's say machine M1's language L(M1)= "abba" then the constructor should produce a new machine M2 such that L(M2)={empty, a, ab, abb, abba}

Now there's a constructor in a library called fsm and it's prototype is like this:

```
    (make-fsa list-of-states alphabet starting-state list-of-final-states list-of-rules)
;List-of-rules is the list of transitions such as (q0 a q1)
;the function returns a finite state machine
```

I am trying to get every state a final state. But does it work?

The code below is what I've got so far:

```
#lang racket
(require fsm) ;provides the constructor and getters

(define M1
  (make-dfa ;constructor, provided by the fsm library
  '(q0 q1 q2) ;states
  '(a b) ;alphabet
  'q0 ; starting state
  '(q2) ;list of final states
  '((q0 a q1) ;list of rules
    (q0 b q0)
    (q1 a q0)
    (q1 b q2)
    (q2 a q2)
    (q2 b q2))))

; new constructor
(define M2 
  (make-dfa
  (sm-getstates M1) ;sm-getstates is a getter that gets a certain machine's states
  (sm-getalphabet M1) ;sm-getalphabet is a getter that gets a certain machine's alphabet
  (sm-getstart M1) ;sm-getstart is a getter that gets a certain machine's starting state
  (sm-getstates M1) ; TURNING EVERY STATE IN M1 A FINAL STATE, BUT DOES IT WORK?
  (sm-getrules M1))) ;sm-getrules is a getter that gets a certain machine's list of rules
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your plan does not work. Consider this machine:

States: S,L,F
Alphabet: a,b
Start state: S
Final state S

S-a->L    (arrow from S to L given a)
S-b->F
L-a->L

Strings accepted by this machine:  {b}

If you make a new machine where L is a final state,
then {empty,a,aa,aaa,...} will be accepted but they are not prefixes
in the original machine.

In your construction of M2, only states of M1 that have a path to a final state should become final states in M2.

Comment: Mange tak. My plan is to get every state of M1 - which means S, L and F the final states. so that the new machine accepts {empty, a, aa, aaa, aaaaaaaa, .... b} and therefore accpets all of the prefixes of M1.

Comment: Det var så lidt. If you add only the states that have a path to a final state, M2 will recognize prefixes of strings accepted by M1 only. If you turn all states of M1 to final states in M2, the language accepted by M2 will be too large.

Comment: Thank you very much again. What method would you use for finding the path to a final state?

Comment: The following algoritm starts with the final states and moves backwards to all states that can reach a final state:  Make a queue Q. Add all final states to the queue. Now loop over states in the queue till it is empty. For each state S in the queue Q: i) mark the state as a final state, ii) put all states that point to S into the queue iii) mark as s as being "processed". This will eventually mark all states that have a path to a final state. In ii) only put previously unprocessed states into the queue.

Comment: Thanks and I got a better understanding. It will be better if you have the time to show me actually implementation. Anyway I am marking this as the answer and have a good day!

Comment: You could post a new question on how to find paths and hope someone answers. Where is the fsm library from?